# Make embedded video 100% height and 100% width

Tags: css, html5-video

I would like to make a video 100% height and 100% width. I don't really need to keep the aspect ratio but would be nice if there is a tiny solution for this.

The last solution I found was:

HTML:

```
<div class="video">
  <video autoplay="" loop="" poster="someimage.pjpg">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
}

.video video {
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
}
```

The problem with this solution is that it will always be higher than 100%. And if I set a max-height then it will shrink the video in the width.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a way to stretch the video to fit the screen?
If so then you're looking for something like this:

Source: http://coding.vdhdesign.co.nz/?p=29

```
$VideoElement = $(_VideoElement); //Cache Jquery reference of this
var iOriginalVideoHeight =  _VideoElement.videoHeight;
var iCurrentVideoHeight = $VideoElement.height();
var iVideoContainerHeight = $VideoElement.parent().height();
var iCurrentScale = iOriginalVideoHeight/iCurrentVideoHeight;
var iScaleY = (iVideoContainerHeight / iOriginalVideoHeight)*iCurrentScale;

//Important to note: Set the origin to the top left corner (0% 0%), or else the position of the video goes astray

$VideoElement.css({
 "transform-origin": "0% 0%",
 "transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")",
 "-ms-transform-origin" : "0% 0% ", /* IE 9 */
 "-ms-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")", /* IE 9 */
 "-moz-transform-origin" : "0% 0%", /* Firefox */
 "-moz-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")", /* Firefox */
 "-webkit-transform-origin": "0% 0%", /* Safari and Chrome */
 "-webkit-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")", /* Safari and Chrome */
 "-o-transform-origin":"0% 0%", /* Opera */
 "-o-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")" /* Opera */
});
```

If what you're trying to do is fit either the width or height of your video to 100% (depending on which is greater) then your CSS should look like this:

```
.video video {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make your video 100% of viewport (screen):

```
.video {
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.35);
}
.video video {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

if you want to keep the aspect ratio of the video, replace last 4 lines with:

```
.video video {
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
}
```

if you want the video centered in the screen, add these rules to it:

```
.video video {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3D(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
```